# Google App Engine - What exception does Transaction.commit() throw when there is a concurrency problem?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

What exception does com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Transaction.commit() throw when there is a concurrency problem?

I want to retry if there is a concurrency issue, but I don't know what exception to catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions.html#What_Can_Be_Done_In_a_Transaction), it raises a [TransactionFailedError](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/exceptions.html#TransactionFailedError). Retrying is a bad idea, though: The error gets thrown when there's too much contention, and retrying will simply *increase* the contention. If you want to change the number of retries, use run_in_transaction_custom_retries, documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html).